# ELASTICSEARCH - Total doc_count aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by

I am looking for a way to sum up the total of an aggregation that I have defined in the query.
For example:

```
  {
      "name" : false,
      "surname" : false
    
  },
  {
      "name" : false,
      "surname" : false
  }
```

Query:

```
GET index/_search?size=0
{"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {"term": {"name": false}},
      {"term": {"surname": false}}
    ]
  }
},
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    },
    "surname": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "surname"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query returns the value for each field "**name**" and "**surname**" with value "false".

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "name" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 0,
          "key_as_string" : "false",
          "doc_count" : 2 <---------
        }
      ]
    },
    "surname" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 0,
          "key_as_string" : "false",
          "doc_count" : 2 <---------
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to return the total sum of doc_count, so that in this situation it would be **"doc_count" : 2 + "doc_count" : 2 == 4**?

I've been trying to do it with script but since they are boolean values it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you need that, you have only TWO docs, where this 4 count could ever possibly come from? What you gonna do with that number, it's totally detached from reality? Could you explain?

Comment: I need to average the results for each document and for each field according to their values, so I need to know the total sum for each document.

Comment: That just doesn't make any sense, really. But whatever you need this oddity for - you're free further process the result you already have with any other tool. Write a script and add it up any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality that most closely resembles the solution I am looking for is [sum_bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html).

```
GET index/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "aggs": {
    "surname_field": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "surname",
          "size": 1
        }
    },
    "sum": {
      "sum_bucket" : {
        "buckets_path":"surname_field>_count"
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

For this specific case where it is a simple JSON, the result of the query is the same as the hits.total.value (number of documents) with filtering to boolean field surname:false or name:false.
But for situations with Json with more fields we can specify the number of times we have a result in our database.
With this result I wanted to find the total number of hits and not the number of documents in the result.